# Gnucash won't start

Tags: command-line, sudo, gnucash

After new installation of Ubuntu 16.04 freshly installed through apt-get Gnucash not working in normal mode. It will starts only in terminal & and requires sudo "sudo Gnucash". After several attempts of reinstall Gnucash nothing has changed. How to fix it to start without terminal and without sudo root permissions?

Comment: I have 16.04 as well but to call `gnucash` I do not use the capital.  Is it possible you created a link using your admin account?

Comment: Another thing you may want to check is to go to your home folder and check what the permissions for folder `.gnucash` are.  It is possible you do not have red/write permissions on that folder.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal, type:

```
$ dpkg -l *gnucash* (that's a lower case L, and *'s are required)

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  gnucash        1:2.6.14-1~g amd64        personal and small-business finan
ii  gnucash-common 1:2.6.14-1~g all          common files for the financial-ac
ii  gnucash-docs   2.6.13-2     all          Documentation for gnucash, a pers
ii  python-gnucash 1:2.6.14-1~g amd64        Gnucash interface for Python
```

If you don't see `python-gnucash` with `ii` in front of its name in this list, install it using `Synaptic`.

Start `Synaptic` from the dash, click the RELOAD icon, click the SEARCH icon, enter "python-gnucash", in the results pane, mark it for installation, click the APPLY icon.